# Is it better to wrap a select statement in a FUNCTION/PROCEDURE when calling from java code?

Tags: java, plsql

I am writing a RESTful service to call some PL SQL procedures I am also writing.  In a few cases, all that is needed is a single piece of information retrieved from a table.

```
SELECT id FROM dual;
```

I am wondering if it is better to wrap this in a `PROCEDURE`, and return the result using an OUT parameter than it would be to simply execute the `SELECT` statement from my REST service?

Or does it even matter?  Is one more secure over the other?

Comment: No, it doesnt make your database access any more secure, it just makes it more complicate. Use prepared statements in your Java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `PreparedStatement` to execute your select statement and if you need to parameterize it use positional parameters (rather than concatenating strings), that will take care of security concerns about SQL injection. You could make an argument for using a stored procedure if there were multiple things you wanted to do and wanted to avoid making round trips between the client and the database, or if there was some Oracle-specific PLSQL you wanted to invoke that you couldn't do through JDBC. Those don't seem to be relevant here so I wouldn't bother with it.